# Fast related tag search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I've got two document sets:

Wikis and WikiTags. Since i want flexible editing of tag names I don't want to embed tag itself into wiki document. So, I store a list of wiki_tag_ids inside wiki document.

I wonder what is the best way to find related tags using this schema. By related tags I mean tags that exist in other wikis tagged with selected tags.

May be I should store related tags in WikiTag document?

Comment: What's your definition of 'related tags'? Are these predefined for each tag, or dynamically determined based on their use in combination with other tags? Please update your question and elaborate on these 'related tags' and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I think that we need more details here. "Related tags" is a very open concept and could mean a lot of things. Off the top of my head, I would pre-calculate related tags for each tag and load that as appropriate, but the details are important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should store to store WikiTag in Wiki document. Mongodb allow easy update, delete single document from nested collection, thats mean 'flexible editing of tag names'.

Collection like this:

```
wikis 
  {
    _id,
    wikiTags {_id, name, ...},
    ...
  }
```

So, for example if you want update nested WikiTag name with `id = SomeTagId` you can:

```
db.wikis.update( {'wikiTags.id':SomeTagId},
                 {$set:{'wikiTags.$.name':"New Tag Name"}},
                  false, 
                  true )
```

If yoy want delete item from nested array you should use [$unset](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24unset),
 add new item: [$push, $addToSet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push)

So, i guess now you see that any operation with nested array can be done easy. And if performance is an issue -- use embedding.

Hope this helps.